# CSS border trick makes DIV unclickable

Tags: css

I made use of a border trick I found somewhere else, basically overlaying a absolute positioned DIV over the content div. It does create the effect though that there is no interaction possible with the original content, i.e. highlighting the text or clicking a button.

```
.stamp-border {
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

I thought adding the z-index should resolve the issue, although it doesn't seem to have any effect. What am I overseeing?

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psteinweber/KRWVA/)

Comment: You might be interested in `pointer-events: none`.

Comment: What's the issue?? It seems to do just what you asked for.

Comment: But why are you giving border in absolute div? you can achieve the same effect giving border in class "post-cta".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still unclear what you're looking for. You currently have a div that is unclickable because of the overlay. If you want that, you could use `pointer-events: none` as I said in the comments and `user-select: none;`. Just note that `user-select` has to be vendor prefixed for compatibility.

If you do want it to be clickable, you could get rid of the overlay altogether. The same style can be accomplished simply like this:

```
<div class="post-cta">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    adipisicing elit. Omnis consequatur deleniti
    earum sed distinctio reiciendis vero sapiente 
    tenetur non natus?  
  </p>
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.post-cta {
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

**[Live demo of both solutions (click).](http://jsbin.com/EvOkeGU/2/edit)**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Getting rid of the overlay doesn't work in my case (the whole setup is more complex than the fiddle), but the other solution works great. I accepted this as the answer as it offers some more details on the issue than the other similar approaches.

Answer (score 4):

just add

```
pointer-events: none
```

The fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KRWVA/2/

Comment: @Era not so nice, imo. Taken from my comment, but it isn't complete. My answer has the complete solution - `user-select: none`.

Comment: Thanks, simple solutions are always appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` will have effect on `position:absolute/position:relative` elements only.
As your text and button is not `position:absolute/position:relative` elements.
.stamp-border will always above them.
Moreover, `z-index` of a chlid element can't smaller then the parent element.

You can create a "container" div to be the parent of both .post-cta and .stamp-border.
Like the following.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="stamp-border"></div>
    <div class="post-cta">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis consequatur deleniti earum sed distinctio reiciendis vero sapiente tenetur non natus?</p>
    <input type="submit">
    </div>
</div>


//CSS Part

.container{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the z-index issue!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry....
Just add..

```
pointer-events: none
```

in your css